# Ternary Operator inside an Arrow Function

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6, ternary-operator

I have a simple Rock, Paper, Scissors game, I've written my function as an arrow function and my if/else as a ternary operator but it returns an error.  It works with a vanilla if / else but not with a ternary.

```
const getUserChoice = userInput => {

  // normalizes all inputs to lowercase
  userInput = userInput.toLowerCase();

  // checks whether the inputs are valid
  userInput === 'rock' || 'paper' || 'scissors' ? return getUserChoice : console.log('please enter a valid entry');

};

getUserChoice('rock');
```

Comment: That's not how `||` works. You have to include the left-hand side with each right-hand side. Also you're probably getting a syntax error because your `return` is in the middle of the expression.

Comment: this doesn't "return an error" at all - this code doesn't even parse as valid code - `SyntaxError: expected expression, got keyword 'return'`

Comment: @Pointy 1. How Would left-hand, right-hand work?  2. Return has to be in the middle because it's the TRUE condition for the statement doesn't it?

Comment: @JaromandaX I get this : 'SyntaxError: Unexpected token return'

Comment: Let's start at the beginning. What should this code do? If the `userInput` is "rock" what should happen? What should happen if the `userInput` isn't one of your three enumerated values? And how would logging that the input wasn't one of those three resolve to a value in the scope of the function?

Comment: `return` is a statement; it cannot appear in the middle of an expression. Your comparisons need to be `userInput === 'rock' || userInput === 'paper' || userInput === 'scissors'` etc

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Right now, I'm just converting the input to lowercase and checking if the input is one of the allowable 3 options.  This is an exercise is syntax, I'm trying to get ternary operators to work inside arrow functions.

Comment: Just to clarify because the title is misleading.  This issue is not related to the arrow notation that is used.

Comment: @BShaps I'm happy to reword it

Comment: @meow-meow-meow please first rewrite it to code that runs, by removing that `return`. The ternary format is `a = b ? c : d` where b is a conditional, and c and d are expressions. There is no `return` in there anywhere. At which point I suspect you just solved your own problem. Remember to look at what the actual error is, and if you know what it means, solve it. And if you don't: tell people what it is after googling what it might mean.

Comment: You might also consider `['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'].includes(userInput. toLowerCase())`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others have pointed out

```
  userInput === 'rock' || 'paper' || 'scissors' ? return getUserChoice : console.log('please enter a valid entry');
```

Is not valid JavaScript. It's not even really a valid construct.

The ternary operators are for choosing A or B based on a condition.

```
 if (condition) {
   return A;
 } else {
   return B;
 }
```

Using the ternary operators that's

```
 return condition ? A : B;
```

but you're returning `getUserChoice` which is function OR you're returning nothing as `console.log('msg')` is not something to return.

It's not clear what you wanted to happen. It looks like you wanted to print an error if the user's choice is not one of `rock`, `paper`, or `scissors`

```
const validateUserChoice = userInput => {

  // normalizes all inputs to lowercase
  userInput = userInput.toLowerCase();

  // checks whether the inputs are valid
  const isValid = userInput === 'rock' || 
                  userInput === 'paper' ||
                  userInput === 'scissors';

  if (!isValid) {
    console.log('please enter a valid entry');
  };

  return isValid;
}
```

???

Note there are faster ways to check if `userInput` is one of many valid options. One might be

```
const validInputs = {
  rock: true,
  paper: true,
  scissors: true,
};
const validateUserChoice = userInput => {

  // normalizes all inputs to lowercase
  userInput = userInput.toLowerCase();

  // checks whether the inputs are valid
  const isValid = !!validInputs[userInput];

  if (!isValid) {
    console.log('please enter a valid entry');
  };

  return isValid;
}
```

It's also probably not best practice to mix validating with error reporting.

```
const validInputs = {
  rock: true,
  paper: true,
  scissors: true,
};
const validateUserChoice = userInput => {

  // normalizes all inputs to lowercase
  userInput = userInput.toLowerCase();

  // checks whether the inputs are valid
  return !!validInputs[userInput];
};

if (!validateUserInput(someInput)) {
  console.log('please enter a valid entry');
};
```

note that the `!!` just makes something that is falsey to actually be false.

```
validInputs[userInput]
```

Will either be `true` or undefined. Often that's good enough but if you really want it to be `true` or `false` then `!!` does the conversion as in

```
const userInput = 'bananas'
const temp1 = validInputs[userInput];   // temp1 = undefined
const temp2 = !temp1;                   // temp2 = true
const temp3 = !temp2;                   // temp3 = false
```

Which is what `!!` is doing

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, your function is what I was trying to do ^, thank you